# A question about Jensen's inequality(probability version)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

> (Jensen's Inequality)
>   Suppose $g(\cdot)$ is a convex function on an open interval $G$ on $\mathbb{R}$. If random variable $X$ is integrable with $\mathbb{P}(X\in G)=1$, $g(X)$ is also intrgrable, then $$\mathbb{E}[g(X)]\geq g(\mathbb{E}[X]).$$

I have confused about how to get $\mathbb{E}[X]\in G$ from $\mathbb{P}(X\in G)=1$? I have tried to use $\mathbb{P}(X\in G)=1$ to get:
$$1= \mathbb{P}(X\in G)=\int \mathbf{1}_{X\in G}d \mathbb{P}= \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{X\in G}],$$

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a<X<b$ almost surely then $a<EX<b$. This follow from the fact that if $Y >0$ almost surely then $EY >0$. (Take $Y=X-a$ first and then $Y=b-X$).